# Sample size problem with length and survival data

Tags: regression, survival, sample-size

I am little stuck here and not sure there is a solution, but asking to see if anyone has any ideas. Here's the situation:

I'm trying to analyse a dataset which is comparing 4 different groups with 3 replicates each (3v3v3v3). Within each replicate there are 20 individuals with no unique ID's (so a total of 60 per group). The study ran for two months and the average length was measured after the first month and after the second month. Using an ANOVA I was able to analyse the differences between these lengths by group successfully, for the first month and second.

Survival was another variable and survival rates are known for each replicate of each group. Additionally, data in the Kaplan-Meier format was provided for the 4 different groups (replicates merged) over the two months. I was able to use a Kaplan-Meier test on this successfully.

Now comes the challenge.

**I need to compare the length by group while considering survival as a confounding variable.** The way I would like to go around is using a regression:

```r
Length ~ Group + Survival
```

However, this won't work: There are only 3 replicates for each group so I have to average the length for each replicate, giving us a sample size of 3, which is too weak to use.

Are there any alternatives?

- I have the Kaplan-Meier data which is more robust but I feel like I can't use it because I can't link it to the individual's length since there are no unique ID's.
- Maybe the data provided just is not possible to analyse in this way, which is also okay!